# Scattering cross-section of a nano-particle with background gas in high vacuum

Tags: vacuum, ideal-gas, estimation, scattering-cross-section

Let's say I have a Silica nano-particle trapped with an optical tweezer in high vacuum (pressure ~ $10^{-6} \mathrm{mbar}$). I know the molar mass of the background gas and its temperature.

How would you calculate the scattering cross-section with the background gas?
Or equally, the number of gas collisions per second?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the cross-section is just

$\sigma = 4 \pi R^2$ with $R$ being the radius of the sphere.
The scattering rate would then be

$\gamma = \sigma n \bar{v}$  with n the particle density and $\bar{v}$ the mean velocity of the gas particles.

Correct?